# How to install pip on python (error : No such file or directory)

Tags: python, django, macos, pip, easy-install

I'm trying to Install Django on my Mac so I have to install pip on Python, and I don't know why the instructions I found on internet don't work for me...

Here is my problem :

`sudo easy_install pip`

```
sudo: unable to execute /usr/local/bin/easy_install: No such file or directory
```

And I'm always getting that "no such file or directory".

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html

Comment: I tried that ! But when i write on the terminal "python get-pip.py", I get this : "python: can't open file 'get-pip.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Comment: If you read the directions from that link, it says: "To install pip, securely download get-pip.py. [2]" get-pip.py in this context is a link. to download the link in your terminal, simply right-click the link and press 'copy link address' then, from the directory you want the software to be downloaded to run the command: "wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py" At that point you can "python get-pip.py". The error you see says, "python: can't open file 'get-pip.py' No such file or directory." That is because you had not downloaded it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the setup script from [here](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) then restart and install with `pip install django`.

Comment: So I run it, then I follow this pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html, but again when I write python get-pip.py, i get no such file or directory

Comment: My guess is you are not running the script from a terminal opened in the same directory.

Comment: @jj_jaq Try the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zPMr0lEMqpo) for additional help.

Comment: @jj_jaq Please mark as answer with the check beside my answer.