# Installing selenium with python with homewbrew

Tags: python, selenium

I have downloaded selenium to my Mac. I am trying to run a script in python using selenium but I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "selenium.py", line 3, in <module>
    from selenium import webdrive
File "/Users/shynds23/python/selenium.py", line 3, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ImportError: cannot import name webdriver
```

My script has these headers:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time
```

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try downloading selenium using pip instead:

```
pip install selenium
```

If pip is not installed on your machine, run:

```
python get-pip.py
```

Here is the link for get-pip:

https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

Comment: I ran the first, and don't have pip, so I ran the second and it gave this error: python: can't open file 'get-pip.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Go to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30146222/how-to-install-pip-on-python-error-no-such-file-or-directory. Scroll down to the only answer and click the provided link "here". It will download get-pip.py. Make sure you move it to your directory where you have python installed. Then, run python get-pip.py

Comment: @ajax1234 Do they need to even include the header "from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException" or are the element related related errors provided with "from selenium import webdriver"?

Comment: I am not sure why the OP has error included, but as you pointed, the exceptions are contained in the library itself.

Comment: I downloaded pip and then selenium using pip, but unfortunately get the same error again...

Comment: Couple of things: first, make sure that your file is not named selenium.py. If so, change the name to something else. Second, make sure you have downloaded selenium in the same directory that you are running your file from. Lastly, try running the command: python -m pip install --upgrade selenium. That generally works when the original downloaded file is not in the right location. I urge you try the latter suggestion first.

Comment: I think changing the name of the file did it. Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad I could help! Please consider accepting the answer so that other users know your question has been answered. Thank you!